# How much does a custom droid PC pay to have extensions in its locomotion systems?

Tags: character-creation, star-wars-saga-edition

A player of mine has decided to create a custom droid as a PC, and as I have gone through the rules to create one, I couldn't find any specifics about this.

The rules state that Medium-sized droids have Walking locomotion, and Small-sized ones have Tracked by default. The player also has 1,000 credits to spend in systems and accessories, but in the appendages section, the locomotion extensions (climbing claws, jump servos, etc) state their cost as "Appendage Cost x 2".

**How many of the "customization" credits must the player expend to afford one of these locomotion extensions?**

Answer (score 1):

The costs for **Droid Locomotion** are in Table 11-3 on p. 188. They reference **Cost Factor**, which is in Table 11-2 on the page before and varies by size.

Per p. 189

> Jump servos double the cost of a walking locomotion system.

The rules make no distinction about when a property is applied, either as part of a new design or as a modification later, so there's some GM discretion involved. You have a few choices...

1. Subtract the cost of the droid's "free" movement system from the doubled cost of the enhanced one. In effect, charge the price (Table 11-3) for whatever the base movement normally costs. "Half" of the doubled cost is free, the other half you need to pay for.
2. Charge the full cost (Table 11-3, then doubled). This reflects that the droid may have been built one way, but was later modified to include a different capability.
3. The base movement is free, and zero doubled is still zero.

I've listed the options from most-to-least fair; #2 is stingy, and #3 is twinky. No matter your decision, take into account the existence of Jedi and Force-enhanced movement. I would only take option #2 for an after-character-creation change, when money is a bit more available and it's logical for the droid character to need to replace or completely rebuild his legs to get the added capability.

<sub>Note: There's a "Military Engineer" prestige class in the Clone Wars book. I don't own it, so I'm not sure if that book may offer additional guidance.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The cost factor comes into play when and if the droid is acquiring different/more/new forms of locomotion. By default all droids start with one form of locomotion for free; walking for medium droids and tracked for small droids. The 1000 starting credits doesn't factor into that as it is already assumed. Afterwards, if they want climbing claws, then they would have to upgrade and the cost factor comes into play.

I hope this answers your question. I'm a little unclear on what you are exactly asking. I know the droid section can be a little difficult to break into at times.

A bit of advice, not related to the rules, Droid-PCs typically need a bit more than the 1000 starting credits for their base model. I found 3000 is a better figure, at least in my experience.

Comment: Yes, but how much is the cost of the climbing claws if they do want to upgrade afterwards? That's what the question is asking; the actual price is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get a chance. Please note that we're not a forum; answer posts should answer the question rather than engaging in discussion (your current answer is mostly OK but, as TuggyNE mentioned, needs to cover the actual cost of locomotion extensions).

Comment: Thank you for your anser, but as @TuggyNE is saying, I would like to know the price of applying that extension later, so I can deduce it from the initial 1000 credits.

Answer (score 0):

The price depends on what size your droid is. 
For instance: A medium droid would need to pay 20 Credits for a Claw. Where as a Colossal droid would have to pay 400 credits for the claw.
(A Medium droid has a cost factor of X1, a Colossal droid has a cost factor of X20. The claws cost is 20X Cost factor. Medium: 20 x 1 =20, Colossal: 20 x 20 =400.)

You find this in droid sizes table on page 194, in the table there is a column named cost factors that will give you all the info you need.

Comment: Let me know if I need to clarify anything.